# unable to connect to forwarded port over ssh

Tags: ssh, postgresql, forwarding

I have two servers. Server 1 has access to an Oracle instance on a server I have permission to hit but not login to via SSH. I would like to use SSH port forwarding to connect from server 2 to server 1 and from there to the Oracle instance.  I have set `GatewayPorts=yes` and `AllowTcpForwarding=yes` but I still feel like something is wrong.

For the purposes of this question, I would like to focus simply on connecting to a postgres instance on server 1 (port 5432)  from server 2 port forward from 16951.

After running:

```
ssh -L 16951:localhost:5432 server1 -nNT -f -g
```

from server 2, I can see `"localhost.16951"` after running `netstat` to check open ports which leads me to believe that the port is listening successfully.

When I run:

```
psql -U jbarton -p 16951
```

I get a message saying that there is no listening port localhost:16951

```
    psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
     Is the server running locally and accepting
     connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.16951"?
```

Any comments, answers or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**Update**

When I now try this with oracle, connect using: `./sqlplus W_USER/password@//localhost:16951/dbname`, I get this error: `ERROR: ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed`

My oracle ora files look like this:

```
`#tnsnames.ora
PROD2 =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 16951))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (SERVICE_NAME = prod2)
      )
    )
```

And the sqlnet.ora

```
'# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
NAMES.LOG_DIRECTORY = /var/oracle/network/log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not specify the hostname psql assumes domain socket connections. As per the man page:

```
If you omit the host name, psql will connect via a Unix-domain socket to a server on the local host, or via TCP/IP to localhost on machines that don't have Unix-domain sockets.
```

Try adding `-h localhost` to the psql command line.

As to the Oracle error, I would guess because of the following (oracle is much harder to diagnose):

```
The ORA-12537 error sometimes relates configuration issues in the sqlnet.ora, protocol.ora and listener.ora files.  Verify that you service names match between your listener and remote client connect strings.
```

So your connect string including `localhost` is being rejected by oracle.

**update**

If that is a local `tnsnames.ora`, have you tried `sqlplus W_USER@PROD2` instead? (it will prompt for a password if required). You may have to set the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` to the location of where `tnsnames.ora` resides.

Comment: That worked, so now that the proof of concept is in place, why doesn't this same process work with oracle? I connect using:
         ./sqlplus W_USER/password@//localhost:16951/dbname

I get this error:

ERROR:
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed

Comment: Updated my answer in relation to the Oracle error.

Comment: Updated my question with my ora files, as far as I can tell they are the same as the ora files on my working system (other than the change to localhost:16951)

Comment: I did have the $TNS_ADMIN  var set and attempted `sqlplus W_USER@PROD2` but I got the same no listener error